# Adding to a list box on another form

Tags: c#, winforms, compiler-errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpO5L.jpg
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9XL4.jpg

how do I take the info from form 1 and add it into form 2?

on form 1 I have many textboxes, a few combo boxes and other stuff, I would like to add these items to a list box on form 2.

this is what I have but its not working

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassofEmployees
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     class employee
    { //will include the attributes of all employees of your organization.

        //fields for employee
      public int employeeId; // 5 digit number to represent employee
      public int ssn; //social security number of employee
      public string name; //employee name
      public int dob; //date of birth
      public int pay; //rate of pay


    }



   class managers : employee
    {
        public string backgroundCheck;
        public string isSalary;
        public string responsibilitys;



    }
    public void getEmployeeData(employee employee)
    {
        try
        {
            employee.employeeId = int.Parse(EmployeeID.Text);
            employee.ssn = int.Parse(SSN.Text);
            employee.name = employeeName.Text;
            employee.dob = int.Parse(DOB.Text);
            employee.pay = int.Parse(pay.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
   private void BCToString()
    {
        string bcSelectedY;
        string bcSelectedN;
        if (bcselect.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            bcSelectedY = bcselect.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        else 
            {
                bcSelectedN = bcselect.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
    }
   public void getMangerData(managers managers)
    {
        if (bcselect.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            managers.backgroundCheck = "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            managers.backgroundCheck = "no";
        }
        if (salary.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            managers.isSalary = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            managers.isSalary = "No";
        }
        managers.responsibilitys = responsibilitys.Text;
    }
    public void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create new employee object
        employee newemployee = new employee();
        //get employee data
        getEmployeeData(newemployee);
            //create new manager object
        managers newmanagerialemployee = new managers();
        getMangerData(newmanagerialemployee);

        EmployeeCumalitveList.employeeList.Items.Add(employee);



    }

    private void done_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeCumalitveList ecl = new EmployeeCumalitveList
       ecl.Show;
        this.Hide();



    }



}



}
```

This is where the errors are:

```
   EmployeeCumalitveList.employeeList.Items.Add(employee);
```

the errors I am getting are:

> Error 1   A new expression requires (), [], or {} after
>   type  C:\Users\T-Ali\Desktop\SHawnasschool\vb.net 2
>   c#\projects\ClassofEmployees\ClassofEmployees\Form1.cs    108 66  ClassofEmployees
>
> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'ClassofEmployees.Form1.employee' is less accessible than method
>   'ClassofEmployees.Form1.getEmployeeData(ClassofEmployees.Form1.employee)' C:\Users\T-Ali\Desktop\SHawnasschool\vb.net
>   2
>   c#\projects\ClassofEmployees\ClassofEmployees\Form1.cs    42  21  ClassofEmployees
>
> Error 3   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'ClassofEmployees.Form1.managers' is less accessible than method
>   'ClassofEmployees.Form1.getMangerData(ClassofEmployees.Form1.managers)'   C:\Users\T-Ali\Desktop\SHawnasschool\vb.net
>   2
>   c#\projects\ClassofEmployees\ClassofEmployees\Form1.cs    70  21  ClassofEmployees

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you make the listbox public?
I believe you can do this by selecting the listbox, going to the properties window, finding the Modifiers item, and setting it to Public.

Second, make sure the form that contains the list of employees, is static, and that you're not creating the same form each time you want to add an employee.
Do this by:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static EmployeeCumalitveList MyEmployeeList;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            MyEmployeeList = new EmployeeCumalitveList();
            Application.Run(MyEmployeeList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the list box is public on form 2. why would I use all the above code what is each purpose? Im new to C# in my text book example their is nothing about having the second form static.

Comment: As I said, the employee form *must* be static. Why? Because think of static this way: a static class is a single class, the same one each time. Each time you make do `new EmployeeCumalitveList()`, you get a new form with an empty list. But if it's static, you have the same form with the same list.

The code above makes a static EmployeeCumalitveList so that the list of employees stays where you want it to. There is no way of calling a local variable from outside of a method, so you must make a static one. (Local variable is one declared in a method, like `ecl` in your `done_Click`.)

Comment: I'm not sure what it writes in your textbook, but like I said, there is no way of calling the same local variables in several methods. You must make it static. Though, you do not have to put it in Program.cs. I just put it there because it's a habit.

Comment: OK that is kinda helpful, but you say that this is the main entry for the program, I actually have my list on the second form not the first does that make a difference?

Comment: Not at all. Just make sure when you want to add an employee to the list you do: `Program.MyEmployeeList.MyList.Items.Add(...)`, where Program is where your static form is in, MyEmployeeList is the name of the static form, and MyList is the name of the listbox. You can change the name of these, and it'll still work.

Comment: Yes it does make a difference! The code I provided is from form1, where as the code for employeecumalitive list is this:                    
namespace ClassofEmployees
{
    public partial class EmployeeCumalitveList : Form
    {
        public EmployeeCumalitveList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
   
    }


    }

Comment: The namespace should be universal, so there is no need to call the namespace when you are going to access a static class. The only time you need to call the namespace is when the method calling is in another namespace, or it is from another project/solution.
As for the EmployeeCumalitveList form, it says public partial class, not static... That means you will be able to make new 'copies' of that form, but you won't be able to access that one directly (unless it has some static variables/methods inside of it). Like I said, you must make a static copy of it.

Comment: You can do this:
`namespace ClassofEmployees
{
    /*This is the static variable*/
    public static EmployeeCumalitveList MyEmployeeList = new EmployeeCumalitveList();
    public partial class EmployeeCumalitveList : Form
    {
        ...
    }
}`
And when ever you need to access the static class, just do `MyEmployeeList.ListBox.Items.....` or add in `ClassofEmployees.` before MyEmployeeList.